# maven Library and Test sources

Tags: maven, jenkins

Once we make a maven project we get library sources under `src/main/java` and test sources under `src/test/java` . Library sources are understandable but what is the purpose of test sources?
What if we don't use this section/folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the folder `src/test/java` or if you don't use just don't create a folder like `src/test` it means the tests will not be compiled nor be executed. So it is no problem if you you don't use the tests, but of course it is recommended to do unit testing.

Comment: Thanks but first half of the question is still there. Why we need to use test sources? Is it only for testing a code by giving some test-cases or is there another function?

Comment: Yes it is only for testing code. Simply put, don't place your test source in src/main/java as they will be pulled to your jar.